# Can I narrow the SPF ranges used by Outlook under Office365?

Tags: outlook, office365, spf

**Supposition**
The SPF record for a domain using Outlook Online services typically involves the `include:spf.protection.outlook.com` mechanism, which in turn cascades into a plethora of IP addresses that are presumably used by Microsoft's distributed hosting.
Presumably this means that if any accounts using these services elsewhere in the world are compromised, they can send out SPAM or similar message content using a forged sender address of any legitimate Outlook Online domain, and still pass SPF ?

**Question**
Given the broad uptake of Outlook Online / Office365, this seems to be a rather large IP range that can compromise SPF. Is there any way to limit which portions of the IP address ranges a domain can use to send from via Outlook Online, and therefore limit the IP ranges in the SPF record for a domain to something less exposed?

**Addendum**
Further to @Synchro's helpful answer, I can see that using DKIM and DMARC together will help mitigate the fact that SPF passes too readily, but DKIM isn't a trivial thing to implement, and I would need to cover other mechanisms in my SPF with DKIM too if I make DMARC rigid. My question remains, is there a way to use a narrower set of outgoing hosts under Office365, maybe with a corresponding subset 'include', in the same way that `include:spf.protection.outlook.com` is a subset of the broader `include:outlook.com` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The short answer: No, you shouldn't want that.**

Basically, you're trusting Microsoft to manage IP ranges, as well as verifying domain ownership in such a way that it is not possible for someone in a tenant other than your own to send on your behalf. The large set of subnets is partially to be able to route efficiently and be able to fail-over in case of datacenter failures.

This is not different with other services that can send email on your behalf, for example Oracle Eloqua (9.344 individual IPv4 addresses) and MailChimp (22.528 individual IPv4 addresses) and Google (322.816 individual IPv4 addresses) all tend to include large and many subnets. [DMARCIAN](https://dmarcian.com/spf-survey/) has a nice tool to check an SPF and see what it is comprised of.

As mentioned in @Synchro's answer, these subnets are meant to be dynamic / flexible and managed by the owner of the service.

I'm not sure if I understand your addendum and @Synchro's answer, with regard to DMARC. The way DMARC works: it looks for **a pass on either SPF or DKIM in order to consider the email authenticated**. There's more to it, such as alignment on domains, but that's a bit our of scope for this question. So as a supplement to your SPF, that would only work if you remove Office 365's SPF include entirely and solely rely on DKIM authentication to satisfy DMARC.

Personally, I like the redundancy of having both, because both SPF and DKIM can be broken in certain scenario's, like mailing lists or forwarding rules. Setting up DKIM per domain in Office 365 is actually quite straightforward. [All you need to do is create 2 CNAME records per domain and enable it.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/use-dkim-to-validate-outbound-email#SetUpDKIMO365)

Finally, SPF is not the anti-spoofing holy grail and you should look into DMARC for this. SPF is checked on the return-path header, not on the email address that the recipient gets to see. So your domain can easily be spoofed while still passing SPF on the domain that is used in the return-path email address, unless you use a restrictive DMARC policy (and the receiving server actually adheres to the DMARC policy).

Comment: Understood and thanks for your comprehensive answer. I think I've come to realise that SPF isn't the panacea I hoped it was.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your supposition is correct, however, it's not safe for you to create subsets of their IP ranges as they could change at any time, along with the source IPs used by your messages, i.e. **O365's SPF record is dynamic**. This is the main reason *for* using `include` mechanisms in your SPF, so you don't have to maintain such ranges. Also bear in mind that even O365's large ranges represents a *very* small proportion of the internet, and an even smaller subset of spoofed message sources.

The right way to do this is to supplement your SPF with DKIM. The combination of SPF and DKIM would get you the results you're after when combined with a strong DMARC policy, because even if someone can get past your SPF, they can't forge your DKIM signatures.

It's possible to get O365 to do DKIM signing for your domain, though it's [a rather convoluted process](https://o365info.com/dkim-domain-keys-identified-mail-basic-introduction-part-1-of-5).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful suggestion, I've added an addendum to my question whcih hopefully explains why this isn't ideal in my particular case.